# Какие речевые ошибки допущены Андреем Платоновым в первой фразе "Котлована"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

В день тридцатилетия личной жизни Вощеву дали расчет с небольшого механического завода, где он добывал средства для своего существования.

Comment: Фраза написана в таком стиле, что сразу становится ясно: это не ошибки, а авторская игра.

Comment: А все-таки, если стоять на позициях практической стилистики, какие правила здесь нарушены?.  Наш преподаватель культуры речи всерьез утверждал, что Платонов - просто безграмотен, и все напрасно восхищаются его стилем. Тогда, в 20-е годы так писали многие писатели из рабочих...

Comment: Преподаватель этот написал много хороших пособий, был пионером введения машинного программирования в преподавание русского языка.

Comment: Я не спрашиваю, с какой целью допущены эти ошибки ( хотя это тоже интересный вопрос), но прошу квалифицировать эти стилистические дефекты. То, что они здесь присутствуют - не вызывает сомнения.

Comment: Какие ошибки и в каком количестве вы здесь усматриваете?

Comment: Здесь, как минимум, три речевых ошибки - фразеологических, лексических, стилистических.

Comment: Не успел исправить текст предыдущего комментария. Я насчитал уже пять ошибок.  Есть также грамматические ошибки. Может, если внимательно посмотреть, их здесь окажется больше.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У каждого своё мнение — ошибки это или особенности авторского стиля. Горького тоже неграмотным считали, а его народный язык был много грамотнее языка иных эстетов.
Корявость, неуклюжесть фразы Платонова бросается в глаза современному читателю, но эта корявость вносит некую иносказательность, чтобы читатель понял, насколько страшно  существование героя (не жизнь).

Если разбирать все "аномальности", можно увидеть:

1. *Дали расчёт* (уволили) — фразеологизм похож на канцелярский штамп *выдали расчёт, рассчитали*.
   Канцеляризм — стилевая ошибка, употребление канцелярского штампа в обстановке быта.
2. Не "работал", а "добывал средства" (канцеляризм).
3. Смысловая избыточность (плеоназм) — "личной жизни".
4. Средства для существования вместо "средства существования (к существованию)" — грамматическая погрешность.
5. Плеоназм — всё придаточное "где он добывал средства для своего существования".
6. Канцеляризм и "средства" вместо "деньги" (только какие там деньги? Их не платили).
7. Книжное философское слово "существование" вместо нейтрального "жизнь".

Но если  "причесать" фразу, получится: «В день тридцатилетия Вощева уволили с небольшого механического завода».

Фраза стала правильной, но исчез психологизм. Сила фразы именно в том, что после слов "в день тридцатилетия личной жизни" (именно *личной*, а не жизни всей страны, о чём должен заботиться советский человек) Вощеву дали не премию за добросовестный труд, а расчет; что Вощев не работал, а "добывал средства" не на жизнь, но "для своего существования".

Герой — продукт времени, когда идеологическим штампом, бюрократической стерилизацией ломался живой язык народа. Отсюда шершавость, корявость, соединение в одно целое несоединимых разностильных слов и выражений, но при этом
виден человек, не утративший своей личности, не растворившийся в массе.

А. Платонов сознательно идет на создание такого текста, который заставляет читателя пробираться через дебри нагромождения странных, неправильных языковых конструкций. Это *его способ* обратить внимание на странность, неестественность, абсурдность обстоятельств, описанных в повести.